# use CoordinatorLayout to hide/show RelativeLayout when scrolling a RecyclerView

Tags: android, coordinator-layout

I have a layout (as generated by android studio) where i added a RelativeLayout to the AppBarLayout. The code is below and it looks like this:

[image]

Where i am stuck: What i want to achieve is when scrolling the Recyclerview down i want that the green relative layout (which has the id 'controlContainer') scrolls out with it, and when i scroll up it should scroll in (not just on the top but at any place i scroll up in the list)

The Toolbar on top should stay where it is.

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/app_bar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
        />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/controlContainer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_green_dark"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"></RelativeLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/frameLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    <include layout="@layout/venue_list" />
</FrameLayout>
```

I thought that using `app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"` in the view that should scroll away combined with `app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"`should achieve that, but it does not do anything. alternatively, when i add those fields to the toolbar itself both layouts scroll away - which is not what i want, i want the toolbar to stay always fixed.

would be nice if anyone could point me in the right direction here? (i hoped it would be possible with using coordinator layout and not hacking some layout manipulation with onscroll listeners?)

Comment: Did you find any solution? I have exactly the same issue... thx

Comment: unfortunately I didn't find an acceptable solution yet

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your toolbar code:

```
app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
```

I found this link helpful: [Scrolling Toolbar](https://mzgreen.github.io/2015/06/23/How-to-hideshow-Toolbar-when-list-is-scrolling(part3)/)

Comment: i played around with those values, but when i do as you suggested then the toolbar and the relative layout scroll away.
but i want the toolbar to stay fixed and just the relativelayout to scroll :(